# how to send the data from a TextField/TextView to another view?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview, delegates

I have 3 TextFields and 1 TextView in my first view (proj1) now i want to show the data from these Fields to the next view on the click of a button-"Done!". How do i do this?
I know its a very basic question, but i've just started off with iphone app dev, any help would be really helpfull.

Comment: got it, :D
    i hadn't shared the delegate object in viewDidLoad :p
    delegateobj = (navigationFunAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    the above line was missing :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this: http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/54859-sharing-data-between-view-controllers-other-objects.html

Answer (score 1):

You can get the value of a textfield with the text property and set the value of the textview with setText

```
[textview setText:[textfield text]]
```

Posting from my android,  hope formatting is fine.

Comment: That was not my question. I wanted to know how to send that data from one view to the other.

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely a big answer. Instead let me post a link - [**How to share data i.e. pass data between different View Controllers and other Objects**](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/54859-sharing-data-between-view-controllers-other-objects.html)

Comment: Actually i just needed the logic. What i found out was, that u need to declare a delegate object and then pass it to another view through which u can access the data.